# Get div td class and append to new div

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html for a calendar

```
<table class="homepagemodule report" id="monthly_calendar" align="center" cellspacing="1">
<caption>
<span>Monthly Calendar</span>
</caption>
<tbody>
<tr class="month_header"><th colspan="5">
<a href="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=123&amp;MONTH=11&amp;YEAR=2013" title="Previous Month">&lt;</a> Jan 2014 <a href="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=123&amp;MONTH=1&amp;YEAR=2014" title="Next Month">&gt;</a></th><th colspan="2"><select name="LOCATION" size="1" onchange="self.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value"><option>Jump To...</option>
<option value="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=123&amp;MONTH=4&amp;YEAR=2013">May 2013</option>
<option value="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=123&amp;MONTH=5&amp;YEAR=2013">Jun 2013</option>
<option value="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=123&amp;MONTH=6&amp;YEAR=2013">Jul 2013</option>
<option value="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=123&amp;MONTH=7&amp;YEAR=2013">Aug 2013</option>
<option value="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=123&amp;MONTH=8&amp;YEAR=2013">Sep 2013</option>
<option value="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=123&amp;MONTH=9&amp;YEAR=2013">Oct 2013</option>
<option value="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=123&amp;MONTH=10&amp;YEAR=2013">Nov 2013</option>
<option value="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=123&amp;MONTH=11&amp;YEAR=2013">Dec 2013</option>
<option value="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=123&amp;MONTH=0&amp;YEAR=2014">Jan 2014</option>
<option value="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=123&amp;MONTH=1&amp;YEAR=2014">Feb 2014</option>
<option value="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=123&amp;MONTH=2&amp;YEAR=2014">Mar 2014</option>
<option value="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=123&amp;MONTH=3&amp;YEAR=2014">Apr 2014</option>
</select></th>
</tr><tr class="day_of_week_header"><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th></tr><tr class="oddtablerow"><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td valign="top"><div class="calendarday">1&nbsp;<a href="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=110&amp;MONTH=0&amp;DAY=1&amp;YEAR=2014" title="Create a New Event On This Day">+</a></div></td>
<td valign="top"><div class="calendarday">2&nbsp;<a href="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=110&amp;MONTH=0&amp;DAY=2&amp;YEAR=2014" title="Create a New Event On This Day">+</a></div></td>
</tr><tr class="eventablerow"><td valign="top"><div class="calendarday">5&nbsp;<a href="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=110&amp;MONTH=0&amp;DAY=5&amp;YEAR=2014" title="Create a New Event On This Day">+</a></div></td>
<td valign="top"><div class="calendarday">13&nbsp;<a href="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=110&amp;MONTH=0&amp;DAY=13&amp;YEAR=2014" title="Create a New Event On This Day">+</a></div></td>
<td valign="top"><div class="calendarday">14&nbsp;<a href="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=110&amp;MONTH=0&amp;DAY=14&amp;YEAR=2014" title="Create a New Event On This Day">+</a></div></td>
<td class="today" valign="top"><div class="calendarday">15&nbsp;<a href="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=110&amp;MONTH=0&amp;DAY=15&amp;YEAR=2014" title="Create a New Event On This Day">+</a></div><ul><li class="calendar_event_trade">No Trades Allowed starts  at 12:00 p.m. (<a href="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/league_calendar_setup?L=24779&amp;EVENT_ID=3126760&amp;ACTION=DELETE&amp;INSTANCE=1389805200" title="Delete This Calendar Event" onclick="return confirm('You are now deleting this league calendar event.\nAre you sure that is what you want to do?');">X</a>)</li>
</ul></td>
<td valign="top"><div class="calendarday">16&nbsp;<a href="http://football21.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=24779&amp;O=110&amp;MONTH=0&amp;DAY=16&amp;YEAR=2014" title="Create a New Event On This Day">+</a></div></td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

I am trying to get the td class "today" pulled from this html and placed in a another div somewhere else on my page , so that i don't have to display the full calendar but only the events on today.  I have tried this jquery to append to another div but its not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#monthly_calendar td.today').appendTo('#todayevents');
</script>

<div id="todayevents"></div>
```

Comment: Try moving your script to the end of the page, before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is running before the document (DOM) is ready.  Your code is fine but because its running too early, its not working. Try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#monthly_calendar td.today').appendTo('#todaycalendar');
});

</script>
```

---

[***$( document ).ready()***](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
>   jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
>   $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included
>   inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire
>   page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your code inside DOM ready to make it works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#monthly_calendar td.today').appendTo('#todayevents');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the code in `document.ready`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#monthly_calendar td.today').appendTo('#todayevents');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/26Yvv/) , just add document ready to your script  so that the script is executed after DOM is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#monthly_calendar td.today').appendTo('#todaycalendar');
});
```

Comment: So you somehow missed the other three answers posted before yours that suggested the exact same thing?

Comment: @j08691 i was preparing the fiddle , when the answers have been posted , i knew the answer before all.